# How to tell if Firefox Home (iOS) is using Data Protection API?

Tags: encryption, web-browser, ios

The source code is here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/services-central/source/fx-home/ What should I be looking/search for? Or even how to extract /ffhomeDB.sq3 and see what it contains.

Comment: I'm not clear on this. Are you asking about FF for iPhone/iPad? Otherwise, what did you mean by iOS? And if so, is there DPAPI for iOS??

Comment: There is DPAPT for iOS and I'm talking about http://www.mozilla.com/mobile/home/

Comment: It would really help the many viewers of this question if you would edit it to be clear without having to follow links.  And what is DPAPT?

Answer (score 2):

Look for uses of the file protection API, for example the file protection classes and constants.

See for example [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/data/NSFileProtectionKey](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSFileProtectionKey)

If it uses keychains it should also be using the keychain protection options.

Generally speaking you'd expect telltale constants and methods such as the following (not exhaustive) to appear in the code if it is aware of the new data protection APIs:

```
NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone
NSFileProtectionKey
NSFileProtectionComplete
NSFileProtectionNone
```

And it should be responding to lock / unlock events, i.e. should implement:

```
-applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable:
-applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable:
```